# How to install Mono on Ubuntu netbook remix 10.04

Tags: ubuntu, mono-framework

How can I easily install the latest version of Mono/MonoDevelop (an IDE for C#) on a machine running Ubuntu netbook remix 10.04?

I can't understand the technical results I got when I searched the 'net.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Mono or MonoDevelop, so I can't be sure, but that VS 2010 tag looks out of place.

Comment: What happens when you try running this from the commandline: `sudo apt-get install mono-devel`? According to http://mono-project.com/DistroPackages/Ubuntu that should complete your mono install.

Answer (score 0):

MonoDevelop is in the official repositories. You can install it via the Ubuntu Software Centre by searching for "MonoDevelop".

Comment: thats it?? is monodevelop equivalent of Visualstudio ?

Comment: can i open visual studio 2010/2008 files on monodevelop?

Comment: @user913233 According to [this](http://monodevelop.com/FAQ#Can_I_import_my_Visual_Studio_2K5.2b_project_into_MonoDevelop.3f), it can.

Comment: if ur saying UBUNTU supports monodevelop, you mean all ubuntu versions?

Comment: @user913233 -_- Yes...